# Exp data syntax

Tags: sql, csv, export

I am fairly new to this. I am trying to export data to a csv file.

When I try to run this:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/myfile.csv'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM TABLE;
```

I get

> incorrect syntax near ‘/tmp/myfile.cav’

Anybody who can help me find a solution?

Comment: tag your database tha you are using

Answer (score 0):

Press `CTRL+shift+F` or in SSMS "Query" menu -> "Results to" set result to file.

Also you can run the query after that Right Click on result query then press on "Save Result as" item ,save as `csv` file.

[image]